# Finding Documentation for CSS Functions

Tags: css

In Visual Studio, I create a new ASP.NET project. It creates a basic construct that one can then go in and edit.

In the Site.css file, there are these calls, I'm guessing each is valid for a different type of browser:

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
```

Believe it or not, I can't seem to find a single entry on the entire Internet for **-ms-linear-gradient**, **-o-linear-gradient**, **-webkit-gradient**, or **-webkit-linear-gradient**.

I'm just trying to find some documentation on what sort of parameters each of these functions is expecting. If they are like javascript, then they accept multiple versions of parameters.

Would someone mind linking or posting a little documentation on here?

Comment: You need quotes when searching for something starting with -, otherwise google will take it as "Not". So search for "-ms-linear-gradient"

Comment: When you search, e.g. via Google, try encapsulating the string in double quotes, e.g. `"-ms-linear-gradient"`.

Comment: That helps a LOT! Thanks to you both.

Comment: Those are [vendor tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/75466380), e.g. `-ms == microsoft, -o == opera, -webkit == standards driven (??, but think chrome and safari), -moz == mozilla/firefox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Primary Resource: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/
- Secondary Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient
- Tips: https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/
- Compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients/

According to CanIUse.com, you can use one ruleset without the vendor prefixes (i.e. just use `linear-gradient`)

- ms: microsoft
- o: opera
- webkit: standards driven (think chrome and safari)
- moz: mozilla/firefox