# Make list items assume height of largest list item

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a group of list items that are essentially containers with some text content. On mobile screen dimensions, I want the height of the containers to be set automatically according to the text content. However, I want all of the containers to assume the same height. So in this case, each container height would equal the height of the tallest container. The codesandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/same-height-list-items-4vmwo3?file=/src/styles.css&resolutionWidth=414&resolutionHeight=675).

As you can see in the screenshot below, on a 414 px screen, the third container in the list is taller than the other two. I want all the containers to assume the height of the third one so that they can be the same.

[image]

How can I accomplish this? Here is the relevant lines of code:

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>Lender Benefits</h1>
  <ul className="list">
    {lenderBenefits.map((benefit) => (
      <li className="benefit_container">{benefit}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
.list {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.benefit_container {
  /* height: max-content; */
  border-radius: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #f1e8dc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS Grid approach (preferred):

```
const styleForEqualHeightRows = { 
  display: "grid", 
  gridAutoRows: "1fr", 
  gap: "1rem" // <= Optional
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Lender Benefits</h1>
      <ul
        className="list"
        style={styleForEqualHeightRows}
      >
        {lenderBenefits.map((benefit) => (
          <li
            key={benefit}
            className="benefit_container"
          >
            {benefit}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's one *(hacky)* approach using JavaScript:

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const lenderBenefits = [
  "No repayment, just reduced margins through credit",
  "A cash advance without predatory interest",
  "Works with your community to bring them in on your mission"
];

export default function App() {
  const list = useRef();
  const [style, setStyle] = useState({});
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    async function handleResize() {
      await setStyle({}); // Break from batch updates...
      const lis = list.current.querySelectorAll("li");
      const heights = [...lis].map((li) => li.offsetHeight);
      const maxHeight = Math.max(...heights);
      setStyle({ height: maxHeight + "px" });
    }
    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return function cleanUp() {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Lender Benefits</h1>
      <ul ref={list} className="list">
        {lenderBenefits.map((benefit) => (
          <li key={benefit} style={style} className="benefit_container">
            {benefit}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```